# Why do some ranges have so many values?

Tags: support

Why do some ranges have so many values? For example:

```
 [0, 2,147,483,647]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is not FORTRAN, spaces are significant and commas are allowed in integers.

Answer (score 1):

That basically says "positive integers"

It is... unlikely that anything on StackOverflow is actually 2 billion+ *anything*.

Comment: You have to allow some headroom for Jon Skeet's rep.